# Out of memory! in Perl program

Tags: perl, out-of-memory

```
sub fetch_ms_table {

  $ms_initial_cnt = 0;
  $logger->info("begin fetching TACCTTREE_MS");

  $SQL = "select $pk_string,LINK_C,LENGTH_Q,PATHS_Q from TACCTTREE_MS tree1 where OUT_Z>\"$process_time\"";

  &execsql($dbp, $SQL);
  $cnt  = 0;
  $cnt1 = 0;

  #load the MILESTONE table data
  while (@data = $dbp->dbnextrow()) {
    $data[0] =~ s/\s+//g;
    $taccttree_ms_cache{ $data[0] }{status}   = "d";    #default the record as deleted.
    $taccttree_ms_cache{ $data[0] }{pk}       = $data[0];
    $taccttree_ms_cache{ $data[0] }{LINK_C}   = $data[1];
    $taccttree_ms_cache{ $data[0] }{LENGTH_Q} = $data[2];
    $taccttree_ms_cache{ $data[0] }{PATHS_Q}  = $data[3];
    $ms_initial_cnt++;
  }

  $logger->info("end fetching taccttree_MS - fetched $ms_initial_cnt rows");
}
```

The above function fails giving the below log,

```
INFO> main::fetch_ms_table begin fetching TACCTTREE_MS 
Failed for 'Milestone TACCTTREE table'

Std Err 
Out of memory!
```

The SQL returns around 5,050,402 rows. The same subroutine is called twice from the main program. The first time it goes through fine and the second time it fails for out of memory

Comment: How much memory does your system have? If you're really tight on memory you'll have to fetch your results in chunks instead of wholesale.

Comment: You are using Perl 4 standards that are around twenty years old. Please add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your program and remove the ampersand `&` from all subroutine calls.

Comment: What is `$pk_string`? And `execsql`?

Comment: Do you need previous query result in `%taccttree_ms_cache` hash before second call? If not, you may want to `undef %taccttree_ms_cache` at the start of the subroutine.

Comment: This is not written by me, am just maintaining the code. execsql is to execute the sql stored in $SQL.

Comment: @tivn: No. It is probably best to leave Perl to look after its own memory, so `%taccttree_ms_cache = ()` is preferable to `undef %taccttree_ms_cache`

Comment: @Meera: I'm trying to find the problem for you, not looking to assign blame. Please show `execsql`

Comment: Just before this sub is being called, there is a %taccttree_ms_cache = ();

Comment: $pk_string is the primary key that is being fetched from the table. I still did not get what do you mean by show execsql.. I thought it is used to execute the sql stmt

Comment: @Meera I think he wants you to post the actual source code for `execsql()`. It isn't built in to Perl so we don't know what it is doing.

Comment: oh, i got it now, here you go,sub execsql
{
        my ($MYDBP, $MYSQL) = @_;
        $MYDBP->dbcmd($MYSQL) || die "Error in dbcmd - $MYSQL";
        $MYDBP->dbsqlexec() || die "Error in dbexec - $MYSQL";
  $MYDBP->dbresults() || die "Error in dbresults - $MYSQL";;
}

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell from your example since you are either using global variables or just using them without declaring them; the previous comment about use strict; etc. is a good one.

My thought is that the $dbp variable (which seems to contain all of the results, based on the body of execsql) is consuming space after each call, and you don't have enough free space when the second call comes around. I suggest making dbp a my variable in this function and clearing it out before you exit the function.

Comment: Will try this suggestion and let you know if it works.